# CSV file with string in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, csv

I have a CSV file that contains string cells, and I want to import it into python. My file is like :

```
header1  header2 header3
abc       1.12    abc 
str1      5.00     str2
```

I want to see the same  format in python as array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert your (assuming tab delimited) CSV file into a list of lists:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(csv_input)
    data = list(csv_input)

print data
print data[1][2]        # row 2, column 3
```

This would give you `data` holding:

```
[['abc', '1.12', 'abc', ''], ['str1', '5.00', 'str2']]

str2
```

If you want to include the header in `data`, comment out the header line.

Comment: Perfect , Thanks .Now I could be able to convert the format of str2 in int !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the csv library: [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

Example with tab seperated csv file:

```
import csv
with open('yourfile.csv', 'rb') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your data are delimited by `'\t'` characters, because it sort-of looks like it.

With builtin Python only:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    table = [line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t') for line in f]
```

With the standard `csv` module:

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
     table = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
     # you could then iterate over `table` or convert it to a static list by saying table=list(table)
```

Either solution gets you a nested sequence where the individual items are all strings, like:

```
[['header1', 'header2', 'header3'],  ['abc', '1.12', 'abc'], ['str1', '5.00', 'str2']]
```

You might also consider installing the popular third-party package `pandas` which lets you slice the table vertically or horizontally and do various types of magic with it:

```
import pandas
table = pandas.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
```

which gets you this:

```
>>> table
  header1  header2 header3
0     abc     1.12     abc
1    str1     5.00    str2

[2 rows x 3 columns]

>>> table['header1'][0]
'abc'
```